# How filter a result of while PHP?

Tags: php

I have a request who select a lot of same result and I try to filter result.
To select the result i use a while PHP like this :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 

    if ($row['id'] == '1') {
        echo 'a';   }
    else if ($row['id'] == '2') {
        echo 'b';   
    } else if ($row['id'] == '3') {
        echo 'c';   
    } else if ($row['id'] == '4' || $row['id'] == '5'|| $row['id'] == '6') {
        echo 'd';
    }
}
```

The Result is : a b c d d d

How can i do to have only this : a b c d ?

The problem is here, you see same icon

[image]

Many thanks,

Comment: use array to store result char and at end show result data

Comment: when you select option 'd' use a variable. Before if is false and when you echo 'd' change it to true.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` maybe...

Comment: @vivek_23 No, it's not  the same problem, please read the problem before to write whatever...

Comment: @EddyVuillaume You want to print `d` once as you mentioned. The attached duplicate does just that.

Comment: I have to agree with @vivek_23 That dup would solve this quite happily. Although I admit I have a bit of a bias :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array and check with in_array,

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row['id'] == '1') {
        if(!in_array('a', $ar))
            $ar[] = 'a';
    } else if ($row['id'] == '2') {
        if(!in_array('b', $ar))
            $ar[] = 'b';
    } else if ($row['id'] == '3') {
        if(!in_array('c', $ar))
            $ar[] = 'c';
    } else if ($row['id'] == '4' || $row['id'] == '5' || $row['id'] == '6') {
        if(!in_array('d', $ar))
            $ar[] = 'd';
    }
}
```

A switch is a better version for your snippet,

```
$ar = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $a = '';
    switch ($row['id']) {
        case '1':$a = 'a';
            break;
        case '2':$a = 'b';
            break;
        case '3':$a = 'c';
            break;
        case '4':case '5':case '6':$a = 'd';
            break;
        default:break;
    }
    !empty($a) && !in_array($a, $ar) && $ar[] = $a;
}
```

At last use implode,

```
echo implode(' ', $ar);
```

Comment: Do you mean strict type checking?

Comment: Updated snippet. You can check now.

Comment: Huzzah :D *filler*

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for PHP 7+:

```
$idMapping = [
    1 => 'a',
    2 => 'b',
    3 => 'c',
    4 => 'd',
    5 => 'd',
    6 => 'd',
];

$letters = [];

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (
        ($letter = $idMapping[(int) $row['id']] ?? null)
        && !in_array($letter, $letters)
    ) {
        $letters[] = $letter;
    }
}
```